Google Sign-In not working on Android in React Native
Introduction:
I'm encountering an issue with Google Sign-In in my React Native project. Recently, the Google Sign-In functionality has stopped working on Android devices. Previously, it was functioning correctly, but now when users attempt to sign in with Google, a popup appears to select the Google account, but nothing happens after selecting an account. It's worth noting that Google Sign-In continues to work as expected on iOS devices.
Below, I've provided the relevant code snippet from the GoogleLogin.js file along with the project details. Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Repository with code that reproduces the issue
I've encountered an issue with Google Sign-In on Android in my React Native project. Below is the code snippet from my GoogleLogin.js file.
// GoogleLogin.js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, Platform } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { COLORS } from "../../theme";
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  statusCodes,
} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
import { setAccessToken } from "../../store/slices/generalSlice";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import axios from "axios";
import { API_URL } from "../../config/constants";
import { useLoginUserMutation, useSignUpUserMutation } from "../../store/api/api";
import { useToast } from "react-native-toast-notifications";

export default function GoogleLogin() {
  const toast = useToast();

  const [gSignIn, setGSignIn] = React.useState()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const [signUpUser, { isLoading }] = useSignUpUserMutation()
  const [loginUser, { isLoading: loginLoading }] = useLoginUserMutation();

   const handleLogin = async (body) => {
    try {
      const res = await loginUser(body)
      if (res?.error) {
        toast.show("Identifiants de connexion invalides", {
          type: "warning",
          placement: "bottom",
          duration: 4000,
          offset: 30,
          animationType: "slide-in",
        });
      }
      if (res.data?.access_token) {
        dispatch(setAccessToken(res.data?.access_token))
        navigation.popToTop()
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  const handleSignUp = async (body, loginSeq) => {
    try {
      const res = await signUpUser(body)
      if (res?.error) {
        // Handle error
      }
      // Handle success cases
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle error
    }
  }

  const checkSocialUser = async (props) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}verifySocialUserId`, { params: props })
    return response.data
  }

  const SignIn = async () => {
    try {
      GoogleSignin.configure({
        webClientId: "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        androidClientId: "xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        iosClientId: "xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      })
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      setGSignIn(userInfo);
      if (userInfo.user) {
        const isGoogleUser = await checkSocialUser({ google_user_id: userInfo.user.id })
        if (isGoogleUser && !isGoogleUser.status) {
          handleSignUp({ email: userInfo.user.email, first_name: userInfo.user.givenName, last_name: userInfo.user.familyName, password: userInfo.user.familyName+userInfo.user.id, google_user_id: userInfo.user.id, register_medium: 'google' }, ()=>handleLogin({ email: userInfo.user.email, password: userInfo.user.familyName+userInfo.user.id }))
        } else if (isGoogleUser.status) {
          handleLogin({ email: userInfo.user.email, password: userInfo.user.familyName+userInfo.user.id })
        } else {
          alert("Some error occurred");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {(isLoading || loginLoading) ? <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} color={COLORS.primary}/> : <TouchableOpacity style={styles.socialLogin} onPress={() => { SignIn() }}>
        <Image
          source={require("../../assets/icons/google-logo.png")}
          style={styles.socialicon}
        />
        <Text style={styles.socialTxt}>Connecter avec Google</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
  },
});

Expected Behavior
I expected Google Sign-In to work smoothly on both Android and iOS devices.
Actual Behavior
Google Sign-In is not working on Android devices. When users click "Sign in with Google", a popup appears to select the Google account, but nothing happens after selecting an account.
Environment
react-native version: 0.72.6
@react-native-google-signin/google-signin version: 11.0.1
Expo version: ~49.0.6
Please let me know if you need any further information. Thank you!

I think you are getting error log in your catch  blog.
You have to try to log in your catch block.
catch(error){
 console.log('error==' + error)
}


It is not logging any error, because it is not entering the catch block. There is some issue in const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

Are this code is smoothly working for iOS devices?

Yes smooth on iOS, and it was working fine on android as well! Don't know what happened :-(
